# garch function in package tseries, how to predict values with the results from this function?

Tags: r, statistics, time-series

I have a series of stock log returns, say, 100 values. I want to use GARCH to predict the volatility at time 101. If I use the garch function from tseries package, I would call it like this:

```
garch(myData, order=c(1, 1))
```

So considering p = q = 1. This function returns an object which contain 100 fitted values (the first being NA), coefficients (a0, a1 and a2) and 100 residuals (again the first being NA). How do I use this information to predict volatility at time 101?

My first guess was calculating:

```
Vol_101 = a0  +  a1 * fitted.values[100] + a2 * residuals[100]
```

But judging by the results I get this is definitely not right. How could I use GARCH information to predict volatility from a time period that was not part of the original data?

Many thanks,

Chicoscience

Comment: I haven't used GARCH models in particular, but since no one else has answered, hopefully this will be helpful: The `predict` function is probably what you need. `R` model fitting functions generally have a `predict` method associated with them. That just means that the predict function will return appropriate predictions for the type of model object you give it. In this case, the `tseries` package  has an associated `predict` method for `garch` model objects. Type `?"garch-methods"` for details, and also of course check out the help for the `predict` function.

Comment: Another option is to fit your model with `garchFit` from the `fGarch` package. It has an associated `predict` method also. See the [`predict-methods` help](http://help.rmetrics.org/fGarch/methods-predict.html) in the `fGarch` package.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps you can use the  `fGarch`package:

```
library(fGarch)
y1 <- myData # store your series of returns in y

# parameter estimates
g = garchFit(~garch(1,1), y1, cond.dist= "norm", include.mean=FALSE, trace=FALSE)  
omega = g@fit$matcoef[1,1]
alpha = g@fit$matcoef[2,1]
beta = g@fit$matcoef[3,1]

sigma2 = omega + alpha * y1[100]^2 + beta*g@h.t[100] # compute sigma2 for t+1

print(sigma2)
```

Answer (score 0):

In package `fGarch`,there is a function `predict` which can help you get volatility out of sample.
example as fellows:

```
library(fGarch)
da=read.table("m-intcsp7309.txt",header=T)
intc=log(da$intc+1)
length(intc)
#numbers of sample is 444 
m4=garchFit(~1+garch(1,1),data=intc,trace=F)
condPre <- predict(m4, n.ahead = 5)
condPre$standardDeviation
```

`standardDeviation` has stored volatility out of sample(from 445 to 449)

`standardDeviation` is just conditional standard deviation!